# Can't locate images with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to use a UIIMagePickerController to select images in my iPad app. When I run the simulator, the popup says: "No Photos. You can sync photos and videos onto your iPad using iTunes.".

What does that mean? I'm running the app in the simulator, how can I tell UIIMagePickerController where to find the images? Can I use images from my Resources group?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator has its own camera roll, but by default it doesnt have any images in it. You cant just tell the simulator to look at a certain folder in your macs file system so you need to add images to the simulators camera roll

the simplest way to do this is to: (repeat for as many images as you want)

> - open the simulator
> - open safari
> - drag an image onto safaris page (so it opens the image)
> - long press on the image and then select save to camera roll

Comment: sorry for the ignorance, what is "long press"? I right click, but I see no option to save to camera roll! There are options to save, but none for camera roll. Thanks

Comment: its a simulator so you have to think of it like the device, there is no right click action because you cant right click with your finger. a long press is pressing and holding down, so on the simulator click and hold